# Python import async tcp server as a module: data exchange not working, Multithreading with modules

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, tcp, server

I am working on the following project: I created a async tcp tcp ip client/ server connection. The client (c# wpf GUI) writes messages to the server (Raspberry pi, Python) and waits for sensor data. The server receive the message from the client and sends back the current sensor data in a loop.

The server/ client application standalone works fine. In the next step I want to use modules in Python. Here are the main parts shown that I want to implement in a seperate Python file:

**Main.py**

- start the async tcp server and run it in the background (thread)
- print the received data from the client
- read sensor data (thread)
- evaluation (optional)
- hand over the sensor data to the async server

Here is the code in python that I have so fare (start the async tcp server):

**Main.py**

```
import thread
import logging
import socket
import asyncore
#Import async server
from AsyncServerPi_Test import Server


if __name__=='__main__':

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(name)s: %(message)s',)
    log = logging.getLogger('main')
    #parameter
    ip = socket.gethostname() 
    port = 12345
    address = (ip, port) # port 0 means the kernel gives port 
    dataFromPi= 'SensorData'
    server = Server(address,dataFromPi) #issue with parameter dataFromPI
    #dataFromClient = server.getDataFromClient() Code is not working!
    #log.debug(dataFromGUI)
asyncore.loop(timeout=1) # checks all client's readable/writable every second
```

**AsyncServerPi_Test.py**

```
import asyncore
import logging
import time
import socket

# Create one or more network channels -- instances of class asyncore.dispatcher. 
# These channels are automatically added to a global map, used by the loop() function.
class Server(asyncore.dispatcher):
    """Receives connections and establishes handlers for each client."""
    def __init__(self, address, dataFromPi):
        self.dataFromPi = dataFromPi
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Server')
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self) 
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind(address) 
        self.address = self.socket.getsockname() 
        self.logger.debug('binding to %s', self.address)
        self.listen(1)

    def timein(self): 
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.logger.debug('init start_time -> %e', self.start_time)

    def handle_accept(self):
        # Called when a client connects to our socket
        client_info = self.accept()
        if client_info is not None:
            # start the timeout clock right away
            self.timein()
            self.logger.debug('handle_accept() -> %s', client_info[1])
            Handler(client_info[0], self.start_time, self.dataFromPi)

    def handle_close(self):
        self.logger.debug('server_handle_close()')
        self.close()

class Handler(asyncore.dispatcher):
    """Handles echoing messages from a single client. """
    def __init__(self, sock, start_time, dataFromPi, chunk_size=1024):
        self.dataFromPi = dataFromPi
        self.start_time = start_time
        # send data per 5 seconds
        self.timeout = 5 
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Handler%s' % str(sock.getsockname()))
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, sock=sock)
        self.data_to_write = []

    def timeout_check(self):
        #Time event
        delta_t = time.time() - self.start_time
        if delta_t > self.timeout:
            self.logger.debug('timeout! -> %e %e', delta_t, self.timeout)
            return True
        else:
            self.logger.debug('no timeout -> %e %e', delta_t, self.timeout)
            return False

    def trigger_close(self):
        return self.timeout_check() 

    def writable(self):
        """We want to write if we have received data and when sendSensor data is on."""
        # the trigger_close here is a hack 
        response = bool(self.data_to_write) or self.trigger_close()
        self.logger.debug('writable() -> %s', response)
        return response

    def handle_write(self):
        """Write as much as possible of the reversed recent message we received."""
        self.logger.debug('write data to GUI')
        if self.trigger_close(): # hack to timeout socket
            self.start_time = time.time()
            #data = self.data_to_write.pop()
            sent = self.send(dataFromPi)
            return
        data = self.data_to_write.pop()
        sent = self.send(dataFromPi)
        self.logger.debug('Send data to GUI:'+ str(sent))
        #if sent < len(data)
            #remaining = data[sent:]
            #self.data_to_write.append(remaining)
            #self.logger.debug('handle_write() -> (%d) "%s"', sent, data[:sent])
        #if not self.writable(): # empty recv
        #self.handle_close()

    def reverse(self, s):
        s = list(s)
        s.reverse()
        s = "".join(s)
        return s

    def handle_read(self):
        """Read an incoming message from the client and put it into our outgoing queue."""
        data = self.recv(self.chunk_size)
        self.logger.debug('handle_read() -> (%d) "%s"', len(data), data)
        data = self.reverse(data)
        self.data_to_write.insert(0, data)
        #return self.data --> didnt work!

    def handle_close(self): 
        """server close only gets called if client decides or after timeout"""
        self.logger.debug('handle_close()')
        self.close()
```

I have some issues with the parameter dataFromPi and dataFromClient. dataFromPi is a input parameter that I handover the instance of the server (server = Server(address,dataFromPi)). I get the following error when I execute the main.py file:

```
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <AsyncServerPi_Test.Handler connected 192.168.0.108:51028 at 0x31ba7d8> (<type 'exceptions.NameError'>:global name 'dataFromPi' is not defined [C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py|write|91] [C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py|handle_write_event|468] [C:\Python27\lib\AsyncServerPi_Test.py|handle_write|75])
Handler('192.168.0.108', 12345): handle_close()
```

I checked the handover of dataFromPi in the AsyncServerPi_Test.py file but I couldnt find a solution.

The next issue I have is that I am not able to print the dataFromClient in the main.py file. Within the AsyncServerPi_Test.py file I can read the dataFromClient (handle_read). I tried to return the received data in handle_read, but I think the return of the data must happen in the class server(). How can I archieve that the server class returns the data from the client so I can print the received data in main.py?

Furthermore the server should run in the background so that I can run other operations parallel (read sensor data from ultrasonic, evaluation...). As an example I want that the main.py should look similar like that:

```
import thread
import logging
import socket
import asyncore
#Import US
import Ultrasonic
#Import async tcp ip server
from AsyncServerPi_Test import Server

def main():
    #Logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(name)s: %(message)s',)
    log = logging.getLogger('main')
    #Parameter for server
    ip = socket.gethostname() 
    port = 12345
    address = (ip, port) # port 0 means the kernel gives port 
    ultrasonicTest = Ultrasonic() # run in a seperate thread?
    dataFromSensor = ultrasonicTest.readSensorData
    serverTest = Server(address,dataFromSensor) # run in a seperate thread?
    dataFromClient = serverTest.receivedData()
asyncore.loop(timeout=1) # checks all client's readable/writable every second 

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

In this context I have the following questions:

- The instance of the server (serverTest = Server(address,dataFromSensor)) must run in a seperate thread?
- Create a new thread for the sensor (ultrasonicTest = Ultrasonic()):
- Is it better to run threads within a module (e.g. start threading within the ultrasonic.py and not in the main.py)
- Synchronize the threads?

I am relatie new in python and I dont have much experience in multithreading. It would be helpful if someone has done some similar projects in python and could give me some tips or reference to similar projects.